# python list of strings, replace all occurences not belonging to a specific sublist

Tags: python, regex, string, lambda

I need to replace a list [device1, device2, device0, device3, device4, device5]
with [color1, color2, color0, color3, color0, color0]
So all devices that are not in [device1, device2, device3] I need to replace with a default color. So far I have:

```
set_colors: Callable[[str], str] = lambda s: s \
    .replace(device1, color1) \
    .replace(device2, color2) \
    .replace(device3, color3)
```

how can I implement the part with all other devices? I tried regex, but I cannot figure out how to include it with a lambda function.

Comment: Are the strings literally `device0` and `color0` or something more complex? If more complex, where do the replacement values come from?

Comment: We don't know what device0, device4, device5 might be, they will be coming from db and can be any string with white spaces. color does not matter, it can just be 'blue'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If strings to be replaced are known, then you can do it this way:

```py
def foo(values: List[str]) -> List[str]:
    replacements = {
        'device1': 'color1',
        'device2': 'color2',
        'device3': 'color3'
    }

    return [
        replacements.get(x) or 'color0'
        for x in values
    ]
```

Use `def` instead of a `lambda` ([PEP8 E731](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)).

But if you *really* need a `lambda`:

```py
foo = lambda values: [replacements.get(x) or 'color0' for x in values]
```